# git log to show only files that were modified only after being merged to master

Tags: git, git-log

We have a folder containing database migrations. These are cumulative and should never be changed. If you need to introduce a change you add a new migration.

Is there simple way in git to only show files *in that folder* that were modified *after* their *first* merge/commit into master branch?

I worked out `git log --graph --name-status --diff-filter=a -- FOLDERNAME` to show most of these changes but I want to limit them to modifications after they entered master. In other words I don't care about the initial history of the file only after it was merged to master.

Edit: `--diff-filter=a` seems better then `--diff-filter=DM`

I'm using git for Windows and Azure DevOps if that is relevant.